# Overriding Plugin Template Files with Child Theme

Tags: plugins, child-theme

So hopefully a simple question. I have a child theme installed and have been able to successfully override changes to a `.php` file that is held in my theme files by uploading it to my child theme.

If I want to copy and tweak a plugin file (`wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/templates/store.php`).

Do I just copy and tweak this file then upload it to my child theme?

I'm assuming a child theme doesn't apply to plugin files? If not, is the best way just to download the current file, make the tweaks then override the initial file with the new one in the plugin category?

Thanks![image]

Comment: Hi. It depends on how the plugin is using the template. If it's simply using `include()`, I don't believe this can be done.

Comment: thanks for the info - I'll reach out to the plugin developer.

Comment: I've added the picture to the original question. Looks like maybe the width of the text box overlaps with the logo, forcing it to a new line. Ideally, they'd be next to each other, or the search box would left align if below. This is really getting out of my abilities lol. Again, much appreciate you.

Answer (score 2):

create plugin folder in your child theme and overtire file in it.
your_child-theme/plugin-folder/templates/filename.php

Answer (score 0):

The plugin must use `wc_get_template()` to load the template `store.php`. You can simply copy this file in your `themes/YOURTHEME-child/woocommerce/`. 
Your child template should be loaded.

Comment: Not necessarily true :(

Answer (score 0):

A child theme is no longer necessary for modifications if you use any of the below plugins, which will help you organize your work much better than a child theme.

[Codesnippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/%5D%5B1%5D) works perfectly for this purpose. There is a free version. Pro version due to be released.

[WPCodeBox](https://wpcodebox.com/) does the same job but it is much more sleek and intuitive. They have a generous lifetime launch offer currently.

Comment: Your Codesnippets link is broken

Comment: And it doesn't look like WPCodeBox lets you override page templates?

Comment: @Rup I added the correct link now, thanks. I haven't ever used a child theme myself as when I needed it I came upon these plugins that solved my problem. Both plugins have active communities on Facebook if you want to ask them something. Codesnippets is free to try out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use the procedure outlined in your question. A child theme’s version of any file will override that file with the same name and path from the parent theme, aka:

`parent_theme/fileA.php` is overridden by whatever is in the child theme at the same path location aka `child_theme/fileA.php` or `parent_theme/dir/file3.php` will be overridden by `child_theme/dir/file3.php`. As long as the relative paths match and the names match. Good luck!